# HTML code of in Visual Studio has gone white, PHP format works fine

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I am select PHP from the bottom bar, the code works fine, if I select HTML (which I need for formatting and stuff), it goes white in color but works otherwise. Attached are the images:

[image]

Now I have read other entries here, and they always say it is the faulty extension, but in my case I haven't installed JS and TS nightly extension nor does any of my extension is showing an error.

Help would be appreciated.